# Regex in VBA to pick out specific patterns

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I am working with Macros and VBA for the first time for work, I have some limited python experience.

I am trying to find and pick out all the cheques in bank data from prior periods and assign them the category "Accounts Payable Cheques". However, when I run my code below, only one cell populates and the left are left with nothing, however there should be alot of cells populated.

I am wondering where I am going wrong?

> 

```
Function trim_all(s) As String
   s = Trim(s)
   s = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
   s = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
   s = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
   s = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
   trim_all = Replace(s, "  ", " ")
End Function
```

```
 
 Public Sub regex()
 
 Dim regexObject As RegExp
Set regexObject = New RegExp
     
Dim CHQ As Boolean
Dim curr As String
Dim description As String

    
Range("i2").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

i = True
Do While i = True
   
    ' get values'
    account = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Value
    curr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -7).Value
    description = trim_all(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Value)
    debit = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
    credit = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value

 
 
            'Have to define the regex pattern as a string
            Dim regexPattern As String: regexPattern = "{chq|cheque|^\d{10}$|^\d{5}$}"
            'Quick check that the regex pattern is not empty (maybe supply the pattern as a function in the future?)
            If regexPattern <> "" Then
                
                'Set flags and pattern--very similar to how it's done in Python
                With regexObject
                    .Global = True
                    .MultiLine = True
                    .IgnoreCase = False
                    .Pattern = regexPattern
                End With
                
                'Test the regex; if it matches then set CHQ=True, otherwise CHQ=False
                If regexObject.Test(description) Then
                    CHQ = True
                Else
                    CHQ = False
                End If
            End If

                'Accounts Payable Cheques - Categorization'
            If CHQ = True And curr = "CAD" Then
                ActiveCell.Value = "Accounts Payable Cheques, CAD"
            ElseIf CHQ = True And curr = "USD" Then
                ActiveCell.Value = ""
            End If
            
      ' continue?'
    next_line = ActiveCell.Offset(1, -7).Value
    If next_line = "" Then
        i = False
    Else
        ' go down 1 cell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    End If
    
 Loop
 

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox ("Regex check done!")

 End Sub
```

Comment: Right click the ribbon and turn on the Debug toolbar. Use the buttons to step through your code and you should see where it is failing. You can set Watches to see the contents of variables or hover over the variables with your mouse.

Comment: FYI you can set up your regex object before you enter the loop - no need to do that over and over.  For `trim_all` you can use a loop `Do While Instr(s, "  ") > 0` instead of having to guess what the max number of replacements might need to be.